# How do I change print setup options (paper source, etc) when printing from the Finder in OS X?

Tags: mac, printing, finder

When I'm in the Finder and I select an image file (.jpg, .png, etc.) to print (File > Print), the file starts printing immediately. I'd like to be able to change various options like the paper source, print quality, etc. How can I do this?

I thought maybe I could create an "application" with Automator to do it but don't see any actions to get to printer options. Do I need to break out Applescript?

P.S.: I've got a HP Photosmart 3210.

Comment: Printing from Finder just opens the file in its default application (e.g. Preview) and invokes its print command, without the options dialog. The whole idea is quick printing, without bothering with the print options -- so what do you gain over opening the file properly, and printing from its viewer?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can open the print window, select the options you prefer, then click 'presets' -> save as '.....'. This should define a reusable printing configuration.

Comment: Yes, but that's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only thing I can do is to change the default printer and paper size in the print and fax preference panel. Theoretically if I select 4x6 as the paper size the printer should be smart enough to change to that paper instead of the 8x10. We'll see.

Comment: Does this work for you? My printer's A4 (and that's the default in the preference pane), and printing from Finder is always letter or something similarly wrong for me...

Comment: No, this doesn't work for me. And I don't recall the situation that made me ask the question! :-) I don't know why I wouldn't make a desktop printer icon to do this. EDIT: I made a desktop printer and tried it. Same problem, no choices, just printing.